# BigQuery Table not updating

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a couple of scheduled queries in BigQuery running daily to append data to two dataset tables (one for each query).
However i've noticed today that we have some days missing from both tables.
I can't find any error logs regarding this and the status of both scheduled queries are successful, no errors, though we have some random days missing from the tables (in the last 14 days we have 4 missing).

Have anyone experienced this kind of issue before?

Thanks for support,
Filipe